# Self-referential Type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I currently have an object similar to the following in a Vue.js app that I'm trying to port over to TypeScript. Note this object's structure is dictated by the [Vuex library](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html):

```
const getters = {
  allUsers(state) {
    return state.users;
  },
  firstUser(_state, getters) {
    return getters.allUsers()[0]
  }
}
```

How can I provide the appropriate type for getters here in `firstUser`?

```
const getters = {
  allUsers(state: State) {
    return state.users;
  },
  firstUser(_state: State, getters: typeof getters) {
    return getters.allUsers()[0]
  }
}
```

Currently I get the following error:

```
[ts] 'getters' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.
```

Update: @basarat determined you can make that error go away by renaming the argument.

```
const getters = {
  allUsers(state: State) {
    return state.users;
  },
  firstUser(_state: State, theGetters: typeof getters) {
    return theGetters.allUsers()[0]
  }
}
```

However, `typeof getters` ends up being `any` rather than the type of the `getters` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really can't understand *why* you need `getters` to act this way, but I'll presume you know what you're doing.

This is a limitation of the TypeScript compiler: it will realize that the type of `getters` is recursive, and gives it an `any` type.  The only way around this is to have a type name for `getters` and use it.  How about a class?

```
class Getters {
  allUsers(state: State) {
    return state.users;
  }
  firstUser(_state: State, theGetters: Getters) {
    return theGetters.allUsers()[0]; // hey, a bug!
  }
}
const getters = new Getters();
```

This now is properly typed, and even shows you a bug in your implementation of `firstUser` (which you fix by, I guess, passing `_state` into `allUsers()`).

Hope that helps.  Good luck.

Comment: That's just how the library I'm using expects getters to be defined.

Answer (score 2):

> [ts] 'getters' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.

There are two getters in scope. The parameter and the variable. Change one.

## Fixed

```
const getters = {
  allUsers(state: State) {
    return state.users;
  },
  firstUser(_state: State, _getters: typeof getters) { // Rename
    return _getters.allUsers()[0]
  }
}
```

## More

There are other errors, but this is the one you are asked help for.

Comment: The only issue here though is that `typeof getters` is `any`, whereas I'm expecting it to return the type of the final getters object.